# Autofac v3, Web Api and the Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a project with both Mvc Controllers and Web Api controllers. 
Everything is wired up using autofac 3 :

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register(x => NHibernateConfigurator.BuildSessionFactory()).SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());

        builder.Register(x => new WebApiTransactionAttribute()).PropertiesAutowired();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());



        builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>();
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

        var container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

The problem is that when I add the [Authorize] attribute (the one from System.Web.Http) I get :

```
Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on type 'System.String'. 
Select the constructor explicitly, with the UsingConstructor() configuration method, when the component is registered.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks.

Comment: is this still an issue? Did removing AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, this is somewhat of a guess but the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` [here](http://api.autofac.org/html/111905AD.htm) looks like it may be too broad a registration:

> Provides registrations on-the-fly for **any** concrete type not already registered with the container.

The Autofac Filter Provider could then be registering all kinds of framework concrete types and getting in a muddle.

It may be if you take this out and put in more targeted registrations it will help, perhaps register by convention instead.

Comment: Agreed - try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. No, removing that didn't work, I'm still getting the same error. And the problem is that I also have classes without interfaces but I want to inject those as well. How could I configure this via convention ?

Comment: Came back to this after some time and realized that I can filter the types that are registered by AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource using the second constructor. Thanks.